# Using substr and instr with join when one column has more values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following 2 Tables:

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

I am trying to select columns by joining Table 1 and 2, based on the Column C, using the following query:

```
Select t1.column A,
t2.Column A,
t2. Column B
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where substr(t2.column C,instr(t2.column c,'=',1,1)+1,3) = substr(t1.column C,1,3)
AND substr(t2.column C,instr(t2.column c,':',1,1)+9,10) = substr(t1.column C,instr(t1.column C,';',1,1)+1,11)
AND substr(t2.column C,instr(t2.column c,':',1,2)+9,10) = substr(t1.column C,instr(t1.column C,';',1,2)+1,11)
```

But unfortunately it does not return any results.
I assume this may be happening because Column C in Table 2 has more values.

If that is the case, how would I get the results I am seeking please?

Comment: Why do the tables even contain such columns? If you are interested in substrings, then store these in separate columns.

Comment: You tagged your request with `plsql` which stands for Oracle's programming language PL/SQL. But your question is on SQL. Which DBMS? Oracle? Comma-separated joins, by the way, were made redundant in Standard SQL in 1992. Please don't use them. Use explicit joins instead (`from t1 join t2 on …`).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Thorsten. Apologies I should have tagged it against SQL and its Oracle. I will use explicit join but I don believe that will solve my question, sorry if I have misunderstood anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use regexp_replace you could transform the "column C" from the second table into the format used in the first table.

Once formatted to the same format they can be compared.
Then only 1 join criteria will be needed.

```
select 
t1."column A" as colA1, 
t1."column B" as colB1, 
t2."column A" as colA2, 
t2."column B" as colB2
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on (regexp_replace(t2."column C", '^\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+).*','\1;\2;\3') = t1."column C")
```

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5062/1/0)

Comment: Nice one. Thanks you very much